# SQL request Exceptions from *

Tags: sql, oracle

If i create a sql database request with a * to get everything about one entry what do i have to do to get everything but one

for example: i want to have all information about the table article (ANR, BNR, BEZ, PC)(i don't want to have PC in it) so i start to write my request like this

```
SELECT a.*
FROM article a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [`select`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SELECT.htm#SQLRF01702) you can use `*` or specify all the columns you need, there's no way to extract everything but one:

```
SELECT ANR, BNR, BEZ
FROM article
```

Consider that using the `*`, even if it's shorter to write, may be dangerous, so I would only use it in simple check queries, and not in code to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to say 'select everything except...'.

I tend to go to the table in the object explorer, right click it and 'script as...' then choose 'SELECT To...' and new query window. It will then list all of the columns so you can remove the ones you do not want to select.

I should add, the above is only relevant for MSSQL and SSMS.